# Minimum time to cross the bridge

Tags: logical-deduction, river-crossing

There are 6 friends A, B, C, D, E and F who want to cross a bridge. However, there are two problems. First, the bridge can only accommodate two persons at a time. Second, it is night and they need the torch every time they cross the bridge (fortunately, they have one). The minimum time required by them to cross the bridge is 4 minutes, 2 minutes, 7 minutes, 11 minutes, 6 minutes and 1 minute, respectively. What is the minimum time in which they would be able to cross the bridge?

Options are -
28
29
30
31

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to cross a river: four people with different rowing speeds](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/287/fastest-way-to-cross-a-river-four-people-with-different-rowing-speeds)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this as a shortest path problem, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3389919/shortest-time-for-passing-the-bridge-tt-1-t-2-t-3-dots-textmax-textmin/3389988#3389988).

For your data, the minimum is

> 29

attained as follows:

```
{B,F} cost = max(2,1)  = 2
{F}   cost = max(1)    = 1
{A,E} cost = max(4,6)  = 6
{B}   cost = max(2)    = 2
{B,F} cost = max(2,1)  = 2
{F}   cost = max(1)    = 1
{C,D} cost = max(7,11) = 11
{B}   cost = max(2)    = 2
{B,F} cost = max(2,1)  = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of similar problems out there, but here's a specific detailed answer:

> *Round 0 -> Starting*:
>  - Left side = 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 11
>  - Right side = None
>  - Total time = 0 minutes
>
>  *Round 1 -> 1 and 2 cross, 1 comes back*:
>  - Left side = 1, 4, 6, 7, 11
>  - Right side = 2
>  - Total time = 0 + 2 + 1 = 3 minutes
>
>  *Round 2 -> 7 and 11 cross, 2 comes back*:
>  - Left side = 1, 2, 4, 6
>  - Right side = 7, 11
>  - Total time = 3 + 11 + 2 = 16 minutes
>
>  *Round 3 -> 1 and 2 cross, 1 comes back*:
>  - Left side = 1, 4, 6
>  - Right side = 2, 7, 11
>  - Total time = 16 + 2 + 1 = 19 minutes
>
>  *Round 4 -> 4 and 6 cross, 2 comes back*:
>  - Left side = 1, 2
>  - Right side = 4, 6, 7, 11
>  - Total time = 19 + 6 + 2 = 27 minutes
>
>  *Round 5 -> 1 and 2 cross*:
>  - Left side = None
>  - Right side = 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 11
>  - Total time = 27 + 2 + 0 = **29 minutes**